# xampp Mysql connection using QT in Windows OS

Tags: mysql, qt, xampp

i am having a problem in connecting xampp mysql and QT. Here is the code that i had found in the net but gives an error:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

        db.setHostName("localhost");
        db.setDatabaseName("sample_datebase");
        db.setUserName("root");
        db.setPassword("");

        if(!db.open()) {
            QSqlError err = db.lastError();
            QMessageBox::information(0, QObject::tr("Error Connection!"), err.text());
            return 1;
        }
```

the error message is:

Driver not loaded

Comment: the problem here is how could i load the driver along with the database and the application?

Answer (score 0):

Qt store all database-specific code within the drivers, such as QMYSQL driver. Compiled drivers are atored as a plugins. Before using plugins you need to build them with installed database libraries.

Detailed descriotion of how to build plugins for different databases under differen OS is described [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/sql-driver.html#supported-databases).